# How can I launch a serverside python program through cgi?

Tags: python, apache, cgi, raspberry-pi

I configured apache2 on my Raspberry Pi to launch .py files like any other cgi file and that works so far.

My goal is to start another python program through the website (it is local so no worries^^)

My code so far in the cgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, subprocess 

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<h1>Test</h1>"
subprocess.call("python /home/pi/test.py")
```

I tried os.system too and the cgi file works fine but it doesn't execute the python file.

Comment: Check if the apache user has permission to execute the file (`su - user_running_apache python /home/pi/test.py`). Also, it's always better to include the full path of the python interpreter.

Comment: Instead of just using `call` and ignoring the result, try `check_call` or `check_output`, and print, log, or otherwise keep track of what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this:

```
subprocess.call("python /home/pi/test.py")
```

Is that it looks through your `PATH` from an executable named "python /home/pi/test.py"—all one program, with the space in the name. You want to pass a *list of arguments*, not a command line. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) explain:

> *args* is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). If passing a single string, either *shell* must be `True` (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

So, do this:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "/home/pi/test.py"])
```

That will look for an executable named "python", and run it with "/home/pi/test.py" as its first argument (and with "python" as its zeroth argument), which is what you want.

It may still not work—`python` has to be on the PATH of your special Apache user, through an accessible path, and executable. Often it's better to pass `sys.executable` or `"/usr/bin/python"` or whatever is appropriate.

Meanwhile, it would be easier (as in not completely impossible) to debug this if you didn't just call `call` and ignore the result. For example:

```
ret = call(["python", "/home/pi/test.py"])
if ret:
    print "Running test.py returned", ret
```

… or …

```
try:
    check_call(["python", "/home/pi/test.py"])
except Exception as e:
    print "Tried to run test.py, got back", repr(e)
```

Or… do you actually want its output to pass straight through to the CGI? If not, you probably want to capture its output and do something to it, like this:

```
try:
    output = check_output(["python", "/home/pi/test.py"])
except Exception as e:
    print "Tried to run test.py, got back", repr(e)
else:
    print "test.py said", output
```